# Android TV app uiautomator test

Tags: android-testing, android-uiautomator, android-tv, leanback

We are trying to utilize uiautomator testing for your TV applications. But the TV widgets (cards etc) does not respond to click event.

My question is that how can we make sure we navigate (with DPAD keys) to the correct UI widget and 'click' it with DPAD_CENTER?

Comment: what is it coming in `uiautomatorviewer` ? Only the same you can code with uiautomator .

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which supports Android TV.

For example this is one extract of a `culebra` generated script navigating using keys

```
device.press('DPAD_DOWN')
vc.dump(window=-1)
device.press('DPAD_DOWN')
vc.dump(window=-1)
device.press('DPAD_LEFT')
vc.dump(window=-1)
device.press('ENTER')
vc.dump(window=-1)
```